# circular import with typechecking

Tags: python

Using the two classes below, they both use each other, but I'm not sure how to use both. The typecheck2 class will be inherited with more defining features, but typecheck1 should work as is. I'm trying to typecheck even though I'm not sure it does a lot in python and perhaps I'm thinking about this too much like Java. Anyway, if there's a way to avoid the circular import that would be appreciated.

testtypecheck1:

```
import testtypecheck2
class typecheck1():
    def __init__():
        self.check2 = []
    
    def insert_typecheck2(self, toinsert: testtypecheck2.typecheck2):
        self.check2.append(toinsert)
```

testtypecheck2:

```
import testtypecheck1
class typecheck2():
    

    def __init__(self, tc: testtypecheck1.typecheck1):
        self.tc = tc
        self.p = 'foo'
        print('statement')
```

module3:

```
import testtypecheck1
import testtypecheck2
s = testtypecheck2.typecheck2()
```

Comment: put commonly used utilities in their own file and import them from your other files.

Comment: So make another module/class that contains the list for typecheck1 and import that file?

Comment: So I used cs95's suggestion, after a few tries I made a practically dummy module for testtypecheck1 that allowed a direct hierarchy for inheritance (testtypecheck2 imports dummy_module, testtypecheck1 imports testtypecheck2). It seems a bit more complex than it should be, but it does work.